# In $mn+1$ positive numbers, we can choose $m+1$ numbers which not exist 2 numbers $a_i | a_j$ or $n+1$ numbers $a_1|a_2|...|a_n|a_{n+1}$ satisfy,

Tags: number-theory

Prove that , In $mn+1$ positive numbers, we always

Or can choose $m+1$ numbers which not exist 2 numbers $a_i,a_j : a_i | a_j$

Or can choose $n+1$ numbers in line, $a_1|a_2|...|a_n|a_{n+1}$ satisfy,

---

My idea using composite number into prime factorization but it is not working.

Let $mn+1$ number sets  $A_i= \left( x_{i1}, x_{i2},...,x_{ip}\right)$ , where $x_{ij}$ is positive numbers ($i= 1,2,...,mn+1$ and $j=1,2,...,p$),

We call $A_a$ is "bigger" than $A_b$ if $x_{ac} \geq x_{bc} \forall c=1,2,...,n$. Else , $A_a$ is " not bigger" than $A_b$.

Prove that,
We always can choose $m+1$ number sets, which each set "not bigger" than the others or $n+1$ number sets, which we can put in the line , $A_i$ "bigger" than $A_i+1$

Answer (score 1):

This is just [Erdős–Szekeres theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem).